# SQL MIN not working correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have a database where I am trying to count the total cancellations and changes. The problem is that their are duplicate rows in the database and I only want to use one row for each id. In the example below, I want my final count to be cancellations:5 , changes:1 . The sum part is working correctly, but the MIN(id) is selecting every row and calculating, instead of only one row per id. Thanks for any help., I have included my sql below

```
cancellations | changes | id  |orderNumber |
--------------|---------|-----|------------|
3             |1        | 5   |4           |
3             |1        | 5   |4           |
2             |0        | 7   |5           |


SELECT SUM(cancellations),SUM(changes)
FROM table_1
WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id)) 
AND orderNumber > 3
AND (cancellations >0) AND id = (SELECT       
MIN(id))
```

Comment: can you show us some rows of data in the table?

Comment: Can you also show desired output based on your example in OP?

Comment: @tshoemake For the above table, it would only count 1 of the id 5 rows. So the final cancellations count would be 3+2=5 and changes would be 1+0=1

Comment: @user3071909, what if there are multiple entries for a specific `id` but different value for `cancellations and changes`?

Comment: @FelixPamittan Their arent. It is simply duplication of data that someone accidently put in

Comment: @user3071909, then my answer will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT
    SUM(cancellations), SUM(changes)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table_1
) AS t
```

Comment: I get an error, "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Are you sure you put the `t` on the subquery.

Comment: It is just a couple of numbers off from being the right total. Is their a way to make it distinct on just the id?

Answer (score 1):

i broke down the parts of your query into smaller ones and made a whole query out of the parts in this sql fiddle, [**Fiddle Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3808d/16)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your requirement correctly, but are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT id, SUM(distinct cancellations),SUM(distinct changes)
FROM table
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, didnt see mysql tag.  Pretty sure it doesnt support ctes.

```
With cte 
as (
select cancellations, changes, id, orders, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                            ORDER BY  id DESC ) RN
 from table1
)
select  
sum(cancellations) as cancellationtotal, 
sum(changes) as changetotal
from cte 
where rn<=1
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ad90/18)